# Sort types by inclusion to each other

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, struct, types

I am now working on my Google Protobuf to C++ converter for UE4. The following structs were made from protobuf's messages. Let's say in Messages.h file they are listed the following way:

```
struct B
{
    int i;
    A b;
};

struct A
{
    float f;
    long l;
};

struct C
{
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

N.B. I can't use forward declarations, and also I can't use pointers, they should be values.

The correct order of initialization is: `A, B, C` (it means if these structures are defined in order `A, B, C`, everything is fine). I have all types and their references to other types, there are also other types: int, float, long in my demo.

I want to sort them in the correct order. How can I do this and how can I tell it is not possible (if types cross-reference each other)?

Comment: If you are asking for a generic and standard c++ solution, it's not possible because c++ has no type reflection feature. You would at least need to supply the types yourself, as well as each of their relevant data members. At that point, you still have a graph sorting problem, which isn't a programming question as much as a mathematical one.

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to figure out how to define these structs once? Consider using a topological sort

Comment: My converter is written in java. I have all message's types and I can tell which types are referenced by an every single type (it isn't a benefit of java, C++ parser for protobuf works exactly the same way)

Comment: Just treat the classes as nodes of a direct graph where edges represent their dependencies, then do [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topological sort worked just fine.

[Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/RChehowski/16a3955e59b21ede1c316ec032ab8af5) which can sort objects using typical topological sort. It also have a couple of functions to manage the graph. Will be flattered if it will help someone.